# Exporting symbols without Exporter

Tags: perl

I am learning how to use packages and objects in Perl.

It has been suggested that I use `Exporter` in order to use the functions and variables of a module that have the `package` directive.

I was curious to know whether there is a way to export symbols without using `Exporter`? In other words, can `Exporter` be emulated in some way?

The reason I ask is due to my assumption that Exporter carries extra overhead for functionality that small, simple scripts that must run as fast as possible don't need, and could be avoided by including that functionality with a few simple lines of code.

Maybe a simple illustration of what I mean might help.

Say I have a module which only does this

```
my $my_string = "my_print";
sub my_print {
  print "$my_string: ", @_;
}
```

which would allow for a lot of small scripts to use `my_print` instead of `print`, with just a simple `require` with the filename of my module (and *very* little overhead).

Then, I wanted to use this in another module that has a *package* declaration, and this no longer works, so now I must use a `package` declaration and therefore `Exporter` in my simple module just to get this to work in the new module.

Having been using Perl for quite a while I am used the fact that almost everything is quite simple, straightforward, and low overhead, so I just feel that there could be such a solution for this. If not, then I would accept an answer that explains exactly why Exporter is the only way.

Comment: Hi @Borodin, I appreciate your desire to tidy up my question to make it more comprehensible, but in doing so, the nuance of what I truly wanted to ask is kind of lost. For the benefit of all reading this, my desire isn't merely to reduce the overhead caused by using `Exporter`, but also to learn what it is doing, and how it is all working. This will help me acquire better practices and shed bad ones.. as well as learn advanced concepts I might not othwerwise. See tobyink's answer for exactly what I was looking for

Comment: It didn't express to me a desire to understand the internals of `Exporter`, but you are free to roll back my change or to add further changes. The reason everyone thinks you want a speed improvement is that you say, *"The reason I ask is due to my assumption that Exporter carries extra overhead ... that small, simple scripts (that should run as fast as possible) don't need (and would be greatly negatively impacted by)..."*. And you don't mention understanding the internal functioning. And *please* don't use `tobyink`'s answer - there is no reason not to use `Exporter`.

Comment: nah, don't worry about it. By "nuance" I meant I myself didn't make it all that clear to begin with. But it's not the internals of Exporter per se I am interested in, but rather what is going on, and why it is necessary. As stated "I was curious to know whether.." not that I am against using it. I want to know why I make the programming choices I am making, and that it's not just because someone told me to, with no clue as to why, or what is actually happening. Just one step in the quest to learn the awesome tool that Perl is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Exporter does is quite simple. Here's how you can do it without using Exporter:

**In Foo.pm:**

```
package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub answer { 42 }

sub import {
  no strict 'refs';
  my $caller = caller;
  *{$caller . "::answer"} = \&answer;
}

1;
```

**In script.pl:**

```
use Foo;

print answer(), "\n";
```

However, as others have said, you really needn't worry about the overhead of using Exporter. It's a fairly small and efficient module, and has been bundled with every version of Perl since 5.0. Whatsmore, chances are you're already loading it somewhere anyway -- many of the core Perl modules (such as Carp, Scalar::Util, List::Util, etc) use it.

*Update:* in an earlier version of the code above, I forgot the `no strict 'refs';`. This is necessary for `*{$some_string}` to work.

Comment: wow, awesome. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! I'm going to try this out and see if it works in what I am trying to do. As an aside, I mentioned in another comment that my concern isn't only the overhead, but also to learn what is happening and how it all works, something I hadn't yet been able to gather from the documentation I had read so far. Your answer takes me a great distance ahead into understanding these things. Thanks!

Comment: [perlmod's "Symbol Tables" section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables) gives a brief explanation of the principles involved.

Comment: As correct as this answer may be, I think it is counter-productive. The OP has gone away to write this code in his own programs when he should be using `Exporter` in every case. The way to avid the overhead of Exporter if you really *must* is to use a fully-qualified name, so just `print Foo::answer(), "\n"`. This functions *exactly* the same way as importing the symbol and calling the subroutine by a local name.

Comment: @Borodin, could you clarify why this would be a bad idea? Is it just because "Exporter already does it", or is there another reason? Also, using the FQN is definitely not the same.. especially when it comes to things like say if I want to use a function with the same name in a different module instead, all I would have to do is change the `require` (or `use`) line, and all occurrences of any functions would just work. Using the FQN would require changing every occurrence of every symbol used. In any case, I would really like to understand what your arguments are for not doing it tobyink's way.

Comment: @Borodin, there are many modules by [pillars](https://metacpan.org/source/DCONWAY/Var-Pairs-0.001003/lib/Var/Pairs.pm) [of](https://metacpan.org/source/MSCHWERN/CLASS-1.00/lib/CLASS.pm) [the](https://metacpan.org/source/PETDANCE/Test-Pod-Coverage-1.08/Coverage.pm) [community](https://metacpan.org/source/BARBIE/Test-CPAN-Meta-YAML-0.22/lib/Test/CPAN/Meta/YAML.pm) that do exactly this. I agree with not re-inventing the wheel, but in this case the wheel is only a couple of lines of code. If the wheel you've been given (Exporter.pm) is slightly the wrong shape for your needs, I see no harm in it.

Comment: @tobyink: Firstly, with all respect, `insaner` is no pillar of the Perl community, and would be better served by the simplicity of `Exporter` to help him code correctly than by any minimal advantage to avoiding it. The second of your examples is the `CLASS` module, whose purpose is *only* to export the `CLASS` and `$CLASS` symbols as synonyms of `__PACKAGE__` and there is no use for the facilities that `Exporter` provides. The last two are for use only in test scripts, and it is a good idea to reduce the dependencies of such modules as far as possible.

Comment: @tobyink:  I cannot understand Damian's avoidance of `Exporter` in the `Var::Pairs` module, especially as it exports many symbols and there is no straightforward way to limit what is imported to only those functions that you need. I have sent him an email asking him about this decision and will write again here if I get a reply.

Comment: @insaner: The *biggest* reason is that, as you say, `Exporter` aready does it. With the functionality already written and no significant overhead there are very few excuses to avoid it. It is much simpler to write (and get correct, and debug) code like `use Exporter; our @EXPORT_OK = qw/ answer /;` than the code in `tobyink`'s `import` subroutine. The additional facilities that `Exporter` provides, such as being able to select which symbols you want to import, and grouping the symbols into sets so that only the name of the set need be specified, clinch the deal.

Comment: @tobyink: As I said, I emailed Damian Conway about his choice to avoid `Exporter` in `Var::Pairs`. He has replied to me, saying *“Pure stupidity on my part. I just uploaded a new release that has the usual export interface”*

Comment: it seems I never accepted your answer. Sorry about that, accepted!

Answer (score 0):

[Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) is definitely low overhead.  There is also a list of alternative modules in the [See Also section](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#SEE-ALSO).

If you're curious, you can do a [search on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Exporter&mode=all) for the module and view [the source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TODDR/Exporter-5.68/lib/Exporter.pm) yourself.  You'll notice that the majority of the "code" is just documentation.  However, honestly if you're this new to perl, you shouldn't be worrying about streamlining your code for being light weight as much as you should be aiming to take advantage of as many resources as possible to make coding quicker and easier.

Just my $.02

Comment: I'm not new to perl, just to using objects and packages (unfortunately, my question was edited by an admin to not include a bit of the explanation I had added as to why I am asking this). But I will definitely be looking into studying the source code for Exporter, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like you're trying to find an excuse to avoid `Exporter`? Have you really had programs that start up too slowly? `Exporter` is loaded and executed only in the compilation phase.

If you are genuinely worried about compilation speed then you should write

```
BEGIN { require MyPackage }
```

and then later

```
MyPackage::myprint($myparam)
```

which involves *no* overhead from `Exporter` at all, or even from the equivalent in-line code.

Yes, the code that actually *exports* symbols from one package to another is just a single line in the code of `Exporter.pm` and you *could* duplicate it. But wouldn't you much rather just add

```
use MyPackage;
```

at the start of you program and know that, from any context, the symbols from `MyPackage` would be correctly exported?

If you have "small simple scripts that must be run as fast as possible" then you should investigate leaving them running as daemons rather than recompiling the Perl each time the program is run.

Comment: it's more so that I may better understand what is happening and why, something I have not been able to gather from all the documentation I have read. In general, if I can avoid having to load and compile another large file (ie, >40 lines of text.. plus any other files it might require) each time I want to just use something simple like "my_print" I would want to do that, even if the actual overhead isn't that great. It's not only about the overhead. As my previous description stated, this is a series of questions I was asking to better understand some problems I ran into.

Comment: Using `MyPackage::myprint($myparam)` doesn't allow me to replace `print`'s with _myprint_ (nor does it let me use the same $my_string across modules), so that's not a viable option. And wouldn't having the `require` in the `BEGIN` block cause all `my` scoped variables declared to be limited to that scope and not the file? In any case, my question was to learn about how perl does things (specifically in regards to symbol sharing), to pick up better programming practices (and lose bad ones I've picked up over the years).. I don't see why the question has to be downvoted.

Comment: @insaner: If you are looking to to pick up better programming practices then *use Exporter*. It was written precisely so that the clunky code that it contains needn't be reproduced in every program that needed that functionality.

Comment: @insaner: No, instead of importing `myprint` into the local package you can call `MyPackage::myprint($myparam)`. This functions *identically* to importing `myprint` and writing `myprint($myparam)` (although your `myprint` takes no notice of any parameters passed) so `$myparam` will be discarded. It *does* use the `$my_string` that is declared in the same package as `myprint`.

Comment: Yes, lexical variables declared within a `BEGIN` block would be restricted to that block, but there are none - it contains just a `require`. If you are looking to to pick up better programming practices then *use Exporter*. It was written precisely so that the clunky code that it contains needn't be reproduced in every program that needed that functionality.